# Change td text with javascript without having id

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make change to td text. But as id I am unable to understand what should I add to get the text. Can anyone help with this one?

I have added ? to **getElementBy** to what should be added to change the text.

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementBy?('Age').text = 'Años';
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
     <tr>
     <td nowrap="nowrap" class="Normal label"> Age:</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Appreciate your help guys.

Comment: Looks like you're using jQuery without having it included, and the TD is missing both the row and the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `getElementByXXX` function that searches for text. You'll have to loop over all the `td` elements, get their current text, and compare it to what you're looking for.

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
[].forEach.call(tds, function(td) {
    if (td.textContent.trim() == 'Age:') {
        td.textContent = 'Años:';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `getElementsByTagName` which will give you a live node array.

Iterate over the list and invoke the methods.

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td'); //<--- array like node list

for(var i=0; i< tds.length; i++) {
   var currTd = tds[i];

   currtd.text = 'Años';
}
```

Also `td` can exist only inside a `table` tag. If you do not nest it inside the parent tag, you might not be able to select it.

You can also use `querySelectorAll` to select the elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('td');
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqzn2dp8/)**

Comment: Probably because there is no `text` property?

Comment: make sure it is contained inside the table tag`<table> <td></td> </table>`